# Typescript Utility type to extract properties from an interface having a specified type

Tags: typescript

I would want to generate a new object type having only the properties of another Object that matches the requested types.
Like Pick do, but specifying the types and not the property names.

For example:

```
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: string[];
  d: { [key: string]: never };
}
```

```
interface B extends PickPropertyTypes<A, string | number>{}
```

The interface B should have only the properties **a: string** and **b: number** resulting in an interface like

```
{
  a: string;
  b: number;
}
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885923/why-wont-typescript-let-me-set-a-value-of-an-object-to-a-string-when-it-recogni) and check this `StringProperty` utility type. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/WokqeW)

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine Thanks, but this is not what I was looking for. In your example the final type get the name of the object's properties. My goal though is to generate a new interface having only that two properties and their types ( I've updated the question to better explain myself )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution than the one already presented is to first introduce a helper type that extract keys of given type but only keys that match the criteria.

Only then helper type is used to create the actual structural type.

```
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: string[];
  d: { [key: string]: never };
}

type ExtractPropertyTypes<T, U> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never; }[keyof T]
type PickPropertyTypes<T, V> = { [K in ExtractPropertyTypes<T, V>]: T[K] }

type Test = PickPropertyTypes<A, string | number>
```

This approach mimics the way `Pick` it build on `Extract` and `Omit` on `Exclude`.

Comment: I was just facing some issue with the other way using some nested types. The type was recognized as never. This fixed the issue and now works much better. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: string[];
  d: { [key: string]: never };
}

type PickPropertyTypes<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never] : T[K]
}

type B = PickPropertyTypes<A, string | number>
//   ^?
```