# Generically filtering on an fp-ts Option property and extracting the value

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I often find myelf implementing the following pattern when using fp-ts:

```ts
interface Person {
    id: number;
    pet: O.Option<'dog' | 'cat'>;
}

const person: Person = { id: 1, pet: O.some('dog') };

// simplest case:
const maybePersonWithPet = pipe(
    person.pet,
    O.map(pet => ({ ...person, pet })),
);

// very often slightly more cumbersome:
const maybePersonWithPet2 = pipe(
    O.some(person),
    O.filterMap(p =>
        pipe(
            p.pet,
            O.map(pet => ({ ...p, pet })),
        ),
    ),
);

console.log(maybePersonWithPet);
console.log(maybePersonWithPet2);
// { _tag: 'Some', value: { id: 1, pet: 'dog' }
```

So this is an option filter but it's on a nested option property, where the value of the nested property is extracted.
I would like to generalise this, so I thought to write a function that I could call as follows:

```ts
function filterAndExtractOption<O, K extends keyof O>(object: O, key: K): O.Option<Omit<O, K> & { K: any }> {
    return pipe(
        object[key] as any,
        O.map(value => ({ ...object, [key]: value })),
    ) as any;
}

const maybePersonWithPet3 = filterAndExtractOption(person, 'pet');
console.log(maybePersonWithPet3);

const maybePersonWithPet4 = pipe(
    O.some(person),
    O.chain(p => filterAndExtractOption(p, 'pet')),
);
console.log(maybePersonWithPet4);
```

What would the correct type definition for the `filterAndExtractOption` function be? I need to pass an object, a property key which must be the key for an `Option<A>` and I also need to extract the `A` type.

I also am wondering if there's a canonical and succinct way of doing this with fp-ts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things we need to take into account before we proceed:

1. As far as I understood, `key` argument should represent only `Option` value
2. This expression `({ ...object, [key]: value }))` in TS always returns `{[prop:string]: Value}` indexed type instead of expected `Record<Key, Value>`
3. `object[key]` should be treated as an `Option` value inside of function scope.

### Let's start from the first statement `1)`

In order to assure function scope that `key` argument represents `Option` value, you need to do this:

```js
type GetOptional<Obj> = Values<{
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends O.Option<unknown> ? Prop : never;
}>;

const filter = <
  OptionValue,
  Obj,
  Key extends GetOptional<Obj>
>(
  obj: Obj & Record<Key, O.Option<OptionValue>>,
  key: Key
) =>
  pipe(
    obj[key],
    O.map((value) => extendObj(obj, key, value))
  );
```

Please see [my article](https://catchts.com/useful-patterns#dependent_arguments) and [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885923/why-wont-typescript-let-me-set-a-value-of-an-object-to-a-string-when-it-recogni) for more details and context.

`GetOptional` - iterates through each key and checks whether value which represents this key is a subtype of `O.Option<unknown>` or not. If it is - it returns `Prop` name, otherwise - returns never.

`Values` - obtains a union of all values in object. Hence `GetOptional<Person>` returns `pet` , because this is a key which represents `Option` value.

### As for the second statement `2)`

I have provided helper function :

```js
const extendObj = <Obj, Key extends keyof Obj, Value>(
  obj: Obj,
  key: Key,
  value: Value
) => ({ ...obj, [key]: value }) as Omit<Obj, Key> & Record<Key, Value>;
```

### As for the third statement `3)`:

Then, we need to represent filtering in a type scope.

```js
type InferOption<Opt> = Opt extends O.Some<infer Value> ? Value : never;

type FilterOption<Obj, Key extends GetOptional<Obj>> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: Prop extends Key ? InferOption<Obj[Prop]> : Obj[Prop];
};
```

`InferOption` - extracts value from `Option`

`FilterOption` - iterates through object and checks whether `Prop` is a `Key` which in turn represents `Option` value. If yes - extracts option value, otherwise - returns non modified value.

Let's put it all together:

```js
import * as O from "fp-ts/lib/Option";
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";

interface Person {
  id: number;
  pet: O.Option<"dog" | "cat">;
}

const person: Person = { id: 1, pet: O.some("dog") };

const extendObj = <Obj, Key extends keyof Obj, Value>(
  obj: Obj,
  key: Key,
  value: Value
) => ({ ...obj, [key]: value }) as Omit<Obj, Key> & Record<Key, Value>;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type InferOption<Opt> = Opt extends O.Some<infer Value> ? Value : never;

type FilterOption<Obj, Key extends GetOptional<Obj>> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: Prop extends Key ? InferOption<Obj[Prop]> : Obj[Prop];
};

type GetOptional<Obj> = Values<{
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends O.Option<unknown> ? Prop : never;
}>;

const filter = <
  OptionValue,
  Obj,
  Key extends GetOptional<Obj>
>(
  obj: Obj & Record<Key, O.Option<OptionValue>>,
  key: Key
) =>
  pipe(
    obj[key],
    O.map((value) => extendObj(obj, key, value))
  ) as FilterOption<Obj, Key>;

const maybePersonWithPet3 = filter(person, "pet");

maybePersonWithPet3.pet; // "dog" | "cat"
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m33qLm)

---

In order t make it composable, just get rid of type assertions and `FilterOption`:

```js
import * as O from "fp-ts/lib/Option";
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";

interface Person {
  id: number;
  pet: O.Option<"dog" | "cat">;
}

const person: Person = { id: 1, pet: O.some("dog") };

type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type GetOptional<Obj> = Values<{
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends O.Option<unknown> ? Prop : never;
}>;

const extendObj =
  <Obj, Key extends PropertyKey>(obj: Obj, key: Key) =>
  <Value,>(value: Value) =>
    ({ ...obj, [key]: value } as Omit<Obj, Key> & Record<Key, Value>);

const filter = <OptionValue, Obj, Key extends GetOptional<Obj>>(
  obj: Obj & Record<Key, O.Option<OptionValue>>,
  key: Key
) => pipe(obj[key], O.map(extendObj(obj, key)));

const maybePersonWithPet3 = filter(person, "pet");

const maybePersonWithPet4 = pipe(
  O.some(person),
  O.chain((person: Person) => filter(person, "pet"))
);
```

Comment: This looks really great, thank-you! However the following doesn't work: pipe(O.some(person), O.chain(a => filter(a, 'pet'))) - TypeScript complains that FilterOption<Person, "pet">' is not assignable to type 'Option<unknown>

Comment: @WayneMaurer updated an answer

Comment: btw, managed to find a solution that gives a more readable type output, see my other answer

Answer (score 1):

So [captain-yossarian from Ukraine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495254/captain-yossarian-from-ukraine) gave me an answer that worked, but the return type in his solution is rather hard to read. Inspired by his answer, I managed to get some help from another person on Discord, and now have a more readable solution. I've also extended the function to take more than one key:

```ts
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type GetOptional<Obj> = Values<{
    [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends O.Option<unknown> ? Prop : never;
}>;

const sequenceProps = <A, Key extends GetOptional<A>>(
    a: A,
    ...keys: Key[]
): O.Option<{ [K in keyof A]: K extends Key ? (A[K] extends O.Option<infer B> ? B : A[K]) : A[K] }> => {
    const out = {} as any;
    let allSome = true;
    for (const key in a) {
        if (keys.includes(key as any)) {
            const value = a[key] as any;
            if (O.isSome(value)) {
                out[key] = value.value;
            } else {
                allSome = false;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            out[key] = a[key];
        }
    }
    return allSome ? O.some(out) : O.none;
};
```

I can call the function as follows:

```
type PetType = 'dog' | 'cat';
type VehicleType = 'bicycle' | 'car';
interface Person {
    id: number;
    pet: O.Option<PetType>;
    vehicle: O.Option<VehicleType>;
}
const person: Person = { id: 1, pet: O.some('dog'), vehicle: O.some('bicycle') };

const maybePersonWithPetAndVehicle = sequenceProps(person, 'pet', 'vehicle');
```

... and the return type is clean; when I hover over the variable, I get:

```
const maybePersonWithPetAndVehicle: O.Option<{
    id: number;
    pet: PetType;
    vehicle: VehicleType;
}>
```

Comment: I am  glad that my answer helped to solve your problem