# TypeScript - Obtain type from all properties having a certain type

Tags: typescript, type-mapping

I have a filter object that comes from an OpenAPI spec; something like:

```js
export interface Filters {
  field1: string[]
  field2: string[]
  field3: boolean
  field4: number
}
```

I'd like to derive a type from that filters interface by selecting the type of the properties:

Something like:

```js
export type MultivalueFields = Select<Filters, string[]>
// type MultivalueFields = 'field1' | 'field2'
```

Is there a builtin for this? How can one get the desired outcome?

Comment: VEry related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885923/why-wont-typescript-let-me-set-a-value-of-an-object-to-a-string-when-it-recogni). See [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzabLm) and my [article](https://catchts.com/useful-patterns#dependent_arguments) with more examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a utility type such as follows:

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]
type Select<T, SelectType> = Values<{
  [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends SelectType ? Prop : never
}>

// typeof A = 'field1'
type A = Select<{field1: string[], field2: string}, string[]>
```

All credit goes to @captain-yossarian from Ukraine

Answer (score 3):

There are several version of types that do this. The most modern one is usig the `as` clause in mapped types:

```
type Select<T, SelectType> = keyof {
  [Prop in keyof T as T[Prop] extends SelectType ? Prop : never]: any
}

// typeof A = 'field1'
type A = Select<{field1: string[], field2: string}, string[]>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=19&pln=2&pc=19#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQQBtUoBnOAbwFgAoOOdBYIgEwEYAuOMmKZAOYBtALp0GTFqwBM3XvyTCx9RszYBmbgCMIEIsExJxqqQBZuSAK4BbLWjoBfOnRgBPMHgDKLYNhgAeABUAGjhvfT9A92AAPjgAXjgAa2BXCHQqYyEABSgIMEQkZNT0uEC4TApAnLywEThQVCRWCnDfGCiPOAB+OFz8uAtgADc0EW5DV0dnWgB6Wbg3D1KAQQS4AHJJNnYNl2i4NcS2v39KbY45PkFRUIvZHmvFB1D5G5EYoA)

You can also use a similar type to pick properties of a specific type:

```
type PickByType<T, SelectType> = {
  [Prop in keyof T as T[Prop] extends SelectType ? Prop : never]: T[Prop]
}

// typeof A = { field1: string[]; }
type A = PickByType<{field1: string[], field2: string}, string[]>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQQBtUoBnOAbwFgAoOOdBYIgEwEYAuOMmKZAOYBtALp0GTFqwBM3XvyTCx9RszYBmbgCMIEIsExJxqqQBZuSAK4BbLWjoBfOnRgBPMHgAKCbAGsAQq4AKu7AADxBADRwAMoswNgwIR4AfHAAvFTGQp5QEGCISHC+wK4Q6HBBcJgUQTl5YCJwoKhIrBRx+onJeAD8cLn5cBbAAG5oItx1g42OzrQA9Atwbh7lcACCGVQmbFw8fIKiANxwTrSreFuZ3n6BPWGUkntyh4qi0c8yrwoCDtHyI4iFJAA)